# Relative interior of a set is the interior of a set and the relation with hyperplane

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

My question comes from the famous book: `convex analysis, Rockafellar Ch. 13 p.113`

[image]

[image]

Note:

1. $\delta^*(x^* \mid C) = \operatorname{sup}\{\langle x,x^*\rangle \mid x\in C\}$: a support function of a convex set $C$.

> My question is how to explain the part underscored by red line?    Why it is the case?   I am also confused about the case where ri$(C)$ = int$(C)$ and the relation between hyperplane.

I know the concept of relative interior; however, I still cannot understand what the author was trying to say.

Comment: If $C$ is contained in a hyperplane, then the interior is the empty set. It is evidence that $C$ not a "solid" set in the space. Think about a 3-D sphere versus a 2-D disc in 3-D space; the latter has an empty interior, but both have a non-empty _relative_ interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hyperplane contained in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{E}$ is an affine set of dimension $\text{dim}(\mathbb{E})-1$. If a set $C$ is not contained in any hyperplane, it means that $\text{dim}(C)=\text{dim}(\mathbb{E})$, in which case $\text{aff}(C)=\mathbb{E}$. In this context the definitions of interior and relative interior just match.